# Relationship between shortest path length and minimum cut capacity

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, ford-fulkerson

In a graph G with each arc capacity is 1 and the shortest length from s to t is k the minimum capacity st cut is O(n^2/k^2), where n is the number of vertices.
n choose 2 gives O(n^2) number of arcs, I'm not sure how to reason further than this to justify the statement. 
If I think that each of the st path is k long, that gives me O(n^2/k) possible crossings. Maybe I'm not quite thinking right. Any kind of input will be much appreciated